# Get with AngularJS Cross-Origin Request block

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, cordova, cookies

It's been a week that I'm stuck on this problem; 
I connect to my server API and retrieve a cookie.

I then do a GET to retrieve the JSON returning well Cookie session but I have a problem with Cross Origin.

It is ok on the side of the API because I get a good status 200.

The response :

=============================================================

RESPONSE :
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    Accept,Origin,Content-Type,X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Wed, 06 Aug 2014 18:50:20 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=100
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.3

THE REQUEST:
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cookie  token=97e437a8db5bf96d01e980a3dd81c30cb4bcbf19; PHPSESSID=kjpqve8tbebhh8u2p6nlu2jki5
Host    myapi.com
Origin  localhost
Referer localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0

Here my request :

```
function loadFeed() {
        $scope.show
      /*  console.log($scope.userid);*/


        $http.get('http://myapi.com/', {withCredentials: true})
            .success(function (data) {

                        $scope.hide();
                        $scope.items = data.data;
                       /* console.log($scope.data); */

                    })
            .error(function(result) {
                        alert("feed ne marche pas");

                    });

    }
```

I try this in myapp config :

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

 }])   

.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider) {
     $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', 'http://myapi.com/**', 'http://www.myapi.com/**']);

 }])
```

I do not understand where is the problem ?

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: I use the 2.0.1 version

Comment: could you please recheck this? The current angular version is 1.2.21 and the beta is 1.3.x

Comment: I'm sorry it's 1.2.12

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, i change  my header on my api :
Before : header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
Now : header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 192.168.1.87:8100');

it works but I don't think it will work when I will compile my mobile application...